# How to make initialisation of usb Token (epass2003) for OpenSC undone?

Tags: smartcard, pkcs#11

To use it with OpenSC for some testing, I reinitialized the smartcard usb token (epass2003/storepass) with the opensc tools:

```
pkcs15-init.exe –E  
pkcs15-init.exe --create-pkcs15 --profile pkcs15+onepin --use-default-transport-key --pin 12345678 --puk 1234567890 --label "Tori"
```

The Token works fine with opensc software with the `opensc-pkcs11.dll` .

But now the Card is not found under java PKCS#11 with both dll's the vendors and the opensc dll. (I use Windows 7 64Bit)
But the big problem is that the token not found anymore by the Feitian software, and so the formatting-tool does not work...

Is there a Way to turn the token back to it's condition on delivery?

Comment: This question *may* be answered if you would show us what the original configuration of the smartcard was. Currently we don't even know the type of the smart card. Any personalization data that was on the card is probably lost though; applications may have survived in the ROM.

Comment: It is an ePass2003 Token, the token is initialized by Feitian with their own filesystem, not PKCS15. And yes information on the token may be lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone run into the same problem, here is the solution:

You need the "Format tool for ePass2003", ask the support for the initialize tool which is able to format the token from PKCS#15 to Feitian file system. It is named like another tool but it is different.

After launching the tool and clicking on initialize, the Token is found by the Feitian tools again.

Comment: OK, this is a very specific issue, but thanks for reporting back togu!